# css jquery div hover in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to make an accordion image gallery that works based off an ordered list. The markup is as follows:

```
<ol>
    <li class="slide">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div><img src="/some/path/" /></div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

The stage URL: http://host3.webdrafter.com/majesticbuildersmn.com/

`slide` class is intended to be the hover state (as illustrated by the red border). Of course it all works great except in IE - the hover state will only hover if it can grab text. I think this is a known issue with IE so is there a viable workaround?

**EDIT**: Needs to work for IE 8+ & adding text to the header div allows IE to catch the hover state but only over the text, no other area of the div

Comment: Is IE throwing an error? If jQuery is handling the slide animation there shouldn't be any problems cross browser.

Comment: There's no errors, it's just that the hover state is only really activated in IE if i throw some text in the div and then hover the text. Otherwise - nothing.

Comment: not IE 7 I assume, the thing does not even look right in 7

Comment: we develop for ie 8 and up so i have no clue what ie7 looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the width and height for IE

I tried it on IE9 and it looks like if you hover the top area, it works but not lower. By top I mean near top and also I am not sure how you defined this slider (js) but when I change the height of header, the visual width seems to change

Edit: for IE 9 I hovered on the red border and it moves other than that it does not work. Maybe it's a z-index issue or something. I am not sure but I hope it helps you to trouble shoot it

Comment: Well you're kind of onto something - the script is to set an inline style on the div but in IE it isn't showing. Using the dev console i was able to set the correct values but it's still quirky.

Comment: ok in that ase you might need to tweak the css to make it work or adjust your script so it is easier for IE to access